# how do I loop a texture atlas animation

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I am trying to animate a dog running by using a texture atlas animation in sprite kit. Everything works fine but I would just like to know how do I loop it so that my animation will keep on running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.animationName =[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:DOG_ANIMATION timePerFrame:0.02]];
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to stop the action from running